# Open Source Document Reviewing Software

Tags: linux, open-source, document-management

sorry in advance if I didn't word my question properly.

I need a open source document reviewing tool and preferably I want to give users different privileges such as user A can only see and comment on pages 1-10 but user B can see and comment on whole document.

It should run on Linux (most likely CentOS) in an internal network. Documents are pdf, docx and rarely xlsx. Only feature I need is commenting on documents, others are extras.

Is there anything like this?

Thanks!